# Failure to execute TAR inside Bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, centos, tar

I type this line on terminal:

```
tar -czf temp.tar.gz  aDirectory/*
```

it works.

I add this line inside a bash script:

```
invalid command name "tar"
    while executing
"tar -czf temp.tar.gz  aDirectory/*"
    (file "./backup" line 3)
```

I have tried also to precede tar by `/usr/bin`. Same problem.

Why?

Comment: Can you please show the script as a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: The script contains just one line: `tar -czf temp.tar.gz  aDirectory/*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message looks like it's reported from [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl).

```
[STEP 116] $ cat backup
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

tar -czf temp.tar.gz  aDirectory/*
[STEP 117] $ chmod +x backup
[STEP 118] $ ./backup 
invalid command name "tar"
    while executing
"tar -czf temp.tar.gz  aDirectory/*"
    (file "./backup" line 3)
[STEP 119] $
```

Comment: `bash /your/backup/script`.

Comment: it's weird how you could run a script with tcl if you don't know what tcl is. :)

Comment: fantastic answer. Is this a tar bug? THANKS!

Comment: it's not a tar bug. wondering how you were invoking the script?

Comment: `./backup` from terminal

Comment: what would you see if you `cat /your/backup/script`?

Comment: just the same line `tar -czf temp.tar.gz aDirectory/*`. I do not see anything like you posted with those STEP entries. Nope. just the one line that is the script itself.

Comment: the error says the file has at least 3 lines. what does the 1st line look like?

Comment: I discovered the problem. I had 2 empty lines before the tar line. One of these lines were holding some invisible character that was messing with the tar line. I removed those lines and the tar is now working. THANKS!